# How to correctly put a dialog inside animation timer in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, gluon, gluon-mobile

I have an animation timer and when i handle the end, if a certain condition is true, i want to show a dialog to the user. When i simply tried to call the dialog after the stop() method i had this exception (only on mobile):

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot enter nested loop during animation or layout processing

So, for this case, i solved it wrapping the dialog inside Platform.runLater() method.

Is this the correct way to handle this case?

If not, which is the correct one?

The dialog i'm using is gluon dialog:

http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.2.0/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Dialog.html

And on this simply show doesn't exist, there's only show and wait.

Comment: I assume you are calling `showAndWait()`. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--) (see the `@throws` section), this should only be called in an event handler. It seems you can get away with calling it in a `Platform.runLater(...)` but this is not explicitly documented AFAIK. Can you call `show()` instead?

Comment: show() doesn't exist in gluon Dialog. Any other suggest?

Comment: Oh, this is Gluon dialog, not the standard JavaFX Dialog? No clue, I haven't worked with that at all.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake. I'll be more specific next time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've added an `Alert` inside an `AnimationTimer` to reproduce the issue:

```
private long count = 0;

public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        private long time;

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (now - time > 1_000_000_000) {
                count++;
                if (count == 5) {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Hi there");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
                time = now;
            }

        }
    };

    setCenter(new StackPane(new Label("Hello JavaFX World!")));

    setOnShown(e -> timer.start());
    setOnHidden(e -> timer.stop());
}
```

This fails whether you choose `javafx.scene.control.Alert`:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: showAndWait is not allowed during animation or layout processing
at javafx.scene.control.Dialog.showAndWait(Dialog.java:328)
```

or `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Alert`:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot enter nested loop during animation or layout processing
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:570)
at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.a(SourceFile:613)
```

and whether you run it on desktop or Android:

```
04-05 17:50:48.289  9592  9627 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot enter nested loop during animation or layout processing
04-05 17:50:48.289  9592  9627 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:585)
04-05 17:50:48.289  9592  9627 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.a(SourceFile:613)
```

The Dialog implementation (JavaFX/Gluon) makes use of `Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop()`, and if you check the Quantum [implementation](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt/src/c8333c59a98f0e47d8ca20b9d2442f5a19835cec/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/tk/quantum/QuantumToolkit.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#QuantumToolkit.java-584):

```
if (!canStartNestedEventLoop()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot enter nested loop during animation or layout processing");
}
```

If you try this inside the animation:

```
@Override
public void handle(long now) {
    System.out.println("In pulse: " + !Toolkit.getToolkit().canStartNestedEventLoop()); 
}
```

you will see that inside the animation your pulse is true: by definition of an animationTimer, `handle` is called precisely on every pulse!

So you can't enter a nested event loop, unless you avoid the call on that instant. `Platform.runLater()` it's just a way to do it a little bit *later*.

So this will work fine:

```
@Override
public void handle(long now) {
        if (now - time > 1_000_000_000) {
            count++;
            if (count == 5) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Hi there");
                Platform.runLater(alert::showAndWait);
            }
            time = now;
        }
}
```